# Updating a column of a dataframe based on another column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to update the value of a column using another column's value in **Scala**.

This is the data in my dataframe :

```
+-------------------+------+------+-----+------+----+--------------------+-----------+
|UniqueRowIdentifier|   _c0|   _c1|  _c2|   _c3| _c4|                 _c5|isBadRecord|
+-------------------+------+------+-----+------+----+--------------------+-----------+
|                  1|     0|     0| Name|     0|Desc|                    |          0|
|                  2|  2.11| 10000|Juice|     0| XYZ|2016/12/31 : Inco...|          0|
|                  3|-0.500|-24.12|Fruit|  -255| ABC| 1994-11-21 00:00:00|          0|
|                  4| 0.087|  1222|Bread|-22.06|    | 2017-02-14 00:00:00|          0|
|                  5| 0.087|  1222|Bread|-22.06|    |                    |          0|
+-------------------+------+------+-----+------+----+--------------------+-----------+
```

Here column **_c5** contains a value which is incorrect(value in Row2 has the string **Incorrect**) based on which I'd like to update its isBadRecord field to 1.

Is there a way to update this field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html) api  and use one of the [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) which meet your needs to fill 1 for bad record.

For your case you can write a `udf` function

```
def fillbad = udf((c5 : String) => if(c5.contains("Incorrect")) 1 else 0)
```

And call it as

```
val newDF = dataframe.withColumn("isBadRecord", fillbad(dataframe("_c5")))
```

Comment: how do I check value of one column and update the other based on that using the withColumn api?

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: Instead of creating a UDF to check just a simple 'contains', wont it be better to use 'contains' within withColumn itself!

Comment: I have used it quite a lot many times. 
df.withColumn("isBadRecord", when(col("_c5").contains("Incorrect"),1).otherwise(0))

Comment: @AvikAggarwal instead of commenting and downvoting on a working answer why don't you answer this question with another answer. and I once again thank for downvoting for a working answer

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reasoning about updating it, I'll suggest you think about it as you would in SQL; you could do the following:

```
import org.spark.sql.functions.when

val spark: SparkSession = ??? // your spark session
val df: DataFrame = ??? // your dataframe

import spark.implicits._

df.select(
  $"UniqueRowIdentifier", $"_c0", $"_c1", $"_c2", $"_c3", $"_c4",
  $"_c5", when($"_c5".contains("Incorrect"), 1).otherwise(0) as "isBadRecord")
```

Here is a self-contained script that you can copy and paste on your Spark shell to see the result locally:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

val schema = 
  StructType(Seq(
    StructField("UniqueRowIdentifier", IntegerType),
    StructField("_c0", DoubleType),
    StructField("_c1", DoubleType),
    StructField("_c2", StringType),
    StructField("_c3", DoubleType),
    StructField("_c4", StringType),
    StructField("_c5", StringType),
    StructField("isBadRecord", IntegerType)))

val contents =
  Seq(
    Row(1,  0.0  ,     0.0 ,  "Name",    0.0, "Desc",                       "", 0),
    Row(2,  2.11 , 10000.0 , "Juice",    0.0,  "XYZ", "2016/12/31 : Incorrect", 0),
    Row(3, -0.5  ,   -24.12, "Fruit", -255.0,  "ABC",    "1994-11-21 00:00:00", 0),
    Row(4,  0.087,  1222.0 , "Bread",  -22.06,    "",    "2017-02-14 00:00:00", 0),
    Row(5,  0.087,  1222.0 , "Bread",  -22.06,    "",                       "", 0)
  )

val df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(contents), schema)

df.show()

val withBadRecords =
  df.select(
    $"UniqueRowIdentifier", $"_c0", $"_c1", $"_c2", $"_c3", $"_c4",
    $"_c5", when($"_c5".contains("Incorrect"), 1).otherwise(0) as "isBadRecord")

withBadRecords.show()
```

Whose relevant output is the following:

```
+-------------------+-----+-------+-----+------+----+--------------------+-----------+
|UniqueRowIdentifier|  _c0|    _c1|  _c2|   _c3| _c4|                 _c5|isBadRecord|
+-------------------+-----+-------+-----+------+----+--------------------+-----------+
|                  1|  0.0|    0.0| Name|   0.0|Desc|                    |          0|
|                  2| 2.11|10000.0|Juice|   0.0| XYZ|2016/12/31 : Inco...|          0|
|                  3| -0.5| -24.12|Fruit|-255.0| ABC| 1994-11-21 00:00:00|          0|
|                  4|0.087| 1222.0|Bread|-22.06|    | 2017-02-14 00:00:00|          0|
|                  5|0.087| 1222.0|Bread|-22.06|    |                    |          0|
+-------------------+-----+-------+-----+------+----+--------------------+-----------+

+-------------------+-----+-------+-----+------+----+--------------------+-----------+
|UniqueRowIdentifier|  _c0|    _c1|  _c2|   _c3| _c4|                 _c5|isBadRecord|
+-------------------+-----+-------+-----+------+----+--------------------+-----------+
|                  1|  0.0|    0.0| Name|   0.0|Desc|                    |          0|
|                  2| 2.11|10000.0|Juice|   0.0| XYZ|2016/12/31 : Inco...|          1|
|                  3| -0.5| -24.12|Fruit|-255.0| ABC| 1994-11-21 00:00:00|          0|
|                  4|0.087| 1222.0|Bread|-22.06|    | 2017-02-14 00:00:00|          0|
|                  5|0.087| 1222.0|Bread|-22.06|    |                    |          0|
+-------------------+-----+-------+-----+------+----+--------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: will the answer still work if `_c5` has `2016/12/31 : Incorrect data` as a value? I guess not.

Comment: You're right, I fixed my answer to reflect the requirement in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to create a UDF and try to convert it do Date format.
If it can be converted then return 0 else return 1

This work even if you have an bad date format

```
      val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
        .appName("test").getOrCreate()

      import spark.implicits._

//create test dataframe
      val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
        (1,"1994-11-21 Xyz"),
        (2,"1994-11-21 00:00:00"),
        (3,"1994-11-21 00:00:00")
      )).toDF("id", "date")

// create udf which tries to convert to date format
// returns 0 if success and returns 1 if failure 
      val check = udf((value: String) => {
        Try(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(value)) match {
          case Success(d) => 1
          case Failure(e) => 0
        }
      })

// Add column 
      data.withColumn("badData", check($"date")).show
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does above answer works if you have different words than incorrect in the field value ?